# Device or resource busy - Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, device, apt-get, package-managers

When doing `apt-get -y upgrade` on a new Ubuntu 14.04 machine with the `ubuntu:latest` (Xenial) image, it raised an error:

```
Setting up makedev (2.3.1-93ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
mv: cannot move 'console-' to 'console': Device or resource busy
makedev console c 5 1 root tty 0600: failed
```

---

I've a fresh install of docker on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04, using these command:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sudo sh
su - $USER # To logout and login
```

Docker for `hello-world` runs fine:

```
$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
78445dd45222: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:c5515758d4c5e1e838e9cd307f6c6a0d620b5e07e6f927b07d05f6d12a1ac8d7
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://cloud.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/
```

When I create an empty docker container with:

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

and ran the following:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y debconf-utils
echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
```

The error:

```
Setting up makedev (2.3.1-93ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
mv: cannot move 'console-' to 'console': Device or resource busy
makedev console c 5 1 root tty 0600: failed
```

is raised when doing the last `apt-get -y upgrade`

The full docker log is on: https://gist.github.com/alvations/ebe7175b984213d6f64a3c779ba3249e

Comment: You shouldn't really ever call upgrade inside a container - just download a newer version of the base image.

Comment: It's already `ubuntu:latest` though.

Comment: Right. So to get the newer versions you will need to do `docker pull` when the image is updated then do your `docker build`.

Comment: Apart from what @AdrianMouat already said about best practices regarding distribution upgrades: I assume upgrading core libraries need special permissions (or won't even work for the Kernel). `makedev` is probably such a library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with other answers/comments that `apt-get -y upgrade` isn't as good an idea as pulling a newer/updated image. Where a particular package is required but out of date in an image, installing that particular package is often enough (since dependencies will be updated as necessary).

**However**, there really is no reason that you shouldnt be able to use `apt-get -y upgrade` and in fact, I'd consider this a bug, similar to but not exactly the same as:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/makedev/+bug/1675163

The part that is failing is the first call to MAKEDEV in the postinst script but this is handled and the script continues. Ultimately this means there is no current issue with installing makedev. **But this may not always be true** so probably requires a bug to be raised with Ubuntu to have docker containers detected as well (somehow).

**Note:** if you care about makedev ruining your docker /dev/ directory currently or want to make sure you get rid of any error condition from installing makedev, the fix for the bug I linked to can be used to trick the postinstall script into not running. The check in the script says:

```
# don't stomp on LXC users
if grep -q container=lxc /proc/1/environ
then
    echo "LXC container detected, aborting due to LXC managed /dev."
    exit 0
fi
```

so if you were to add an environment variable whose name ends in container with the value lxc, then the check would be tripped and no new devices would be installed

```
docker run -ti -e "ImNotAnLXCcontainer=lxc" ubuntu
```

This will cause the script to exit, not create a whole bunch of /dev/ entries, and output the message:

```
Setting up makedev (2.3.1-93ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
LXC container detected, aborting due to LXC managed /dev.
```

Answer (score 3):

Docker containers aren't full VMs. They share the kernel with the host, so it's not surprising that some low-level operations, such as making devices, will fail. However, I do note that the command doesn't fail despite the error message - the command returns 0. I would suggest that the container actually works as expected.

Despite this, the best answer is simply not to run `apt-get upgrade`. You're using the `ubuntu:latest` image, which is kept up-to-date by Docker with new versions. So, rather than do `apt-get upgrade` to get a new version, just do `docker pull ubuntu:latest`.

You can check when the `latest` image was last updated here https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/master/repos/ubuntu/remote/latest.md. At the time of writing, the last update was over 6 weeks ago, so it will be missing some updates. Whilst I'm disappointed that it's not more up-to-date, I would still recommend against running `upgrade` as you are likely to have problems and are moving the responsibility for updates onto yourself. Please open an issue if there is an important update that is missing.

I do note that the `debian` image seems to be kept more up-to-date, probably because it is used as a base image for many of the official images - I would recommend using this if possible.

Comment: `docker pull ubuntu:latest` returns `Status: Image is up to date for ubuntu:latest` but there are still quite a lot to be upgraded in `apt-get upgrade` after the `docker pull`

Comment: Fair point. To quantify, at the time of writing, there are 8 packages out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on ubuntu 20.04, and got the same issue. My solution was rebooting my pc